# what's a good training set for a solr search-based calendar entry recognizer?

Tags: solr, calendar, artificial-intelligence, training-data

We're looking to build a system that matches calendar entries to topic from management. We need to find training sets to teach & tune that system. Looking for where we might find a prepared set, or other source.

Comment: Training sets needs to be tuned to the kind of entries you'll see and the topics you're matching, so you'll probably have to build it yourself for any useful classification in a limited setting.

Comment: Thanks MatsLindh - what I was afraid of...